# Trigger on CollaborationGroupMemberRequest

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter, community, collaborationgroup

Is there a way to enable triggers on CollaborationGroupMemberRequest object? I know you can enable triggers on ChatterMessage by setting the correct permission in a cloned System Administrator profile, but I did not see any documentation CollaborationGroupMemberRequest.

What I need to do is create a record in a custom object whenever a group request is made and approved/rejected. I'm not sure if there is a way to accomplish using CollaborationGroupMember. As of now I'm leaning towards adding an action to the group request button on the group page. Pretty new to communities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a trigger on CollaborationGroupMemberRequest as the object does not support triggers .

By default when a request to join a private group is made these records are created and an email is sent to group owner to approve or reject .

A button or action will appear on the group .In case it is missing add all the actions on the page layout of the groups .

Make sure to add membership related list to the group layout .

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. Yes, I have a request to join button setup, so I will add an action page button. The communities I'm working on is all custom Visualforce.